# Javascript: Using font icons in svg's. How do I use "\u"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

I am using **font icons** generated by [icomoon.com](http://icomoon.com) and displaying them as **svg text** using [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Paper.text).

Basically, I have icons like these:

```
&#xe005;
&#xf331;
&#xe0c1;
&#xf003;
&#x25;
```

I have been inserting them into my code like so:

```
paper.text(x, y, iconString).attr({
   'text-anchor': 'end', 
   'font-family':'myFont', 
   'font-size':12})
```

BUT, in order for me to get this to work, I've had to use the Javascript way to show icons, but I don't really know enough about it to know what I'm doing wrong. For example:

```
iconString = "\ue005"; //This is for icon "&#xe005;". Works!
iconString = "\uf331"; //This is for icon "&#xf331;". Works!
iconString = "\ue0c1"; //This is for icon "&#xe0c1;". Works!
iconString = "\uf003"; //This is for icon "&#xf003;". Works!
iconString = "\u25"; //This is for icon "&#x25;". DOES NOT WORK!
```

So I've just been replacing "&#x" with "\u" and it has been working... but not when it is short. :/ How do I do this?

I've also used the whole string (like `"&#xf003;"`, but that has only been working in text and not svg for me.)

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\u` requires four digits.

```
iconString = "\u0025";
```

Alternatively, two-digit numbers can also be done like so:

```
iconString = "\x25";
```

Alternatively alternatively, you can just use the plain character:

```
iconString = "%";
```

Comment: Worked!!! Thank you!! It's too early to accept this answer, so I'll accept in 6 min